# Mozilla NSS building

Tags: command-line, networking, compiling, environment-variables, mozilla

In this instruction :"In order to start the build process, use "cd nss" and execute "make nss_build_all". By default this will produce a build in debug mode and for a 32-bit architecture. You may set the environment variable BUILD_OPT=1 to get an optimized build, and/or variable USE_64=1 to get a 64-bit build."

**which command i use to set the environment variable BUILD_OPT=1 and USE_64=1**  ???

Answer (score 1):

One time for the duration of the session (ie. the compiling of the software):

```
BUILD_OPT=1
USE_64=1 
export BUILD_OPT
export USE_64
```

You need to issue this before the `make nss_build_all`.